# Is there any way to cancel a Mouse Click Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I want to cancel either a mouse click, mouse up, or mouse down even when it occurs on my .NET control.

I was hoping there would be a Cancel parameter in the `EventArgs` but I do not see one like in the `TreeView.BeforeCheck`.

Is there another way I could do this or another event I should listen to?

Comment: The reason I asked this was because of an issue I was having which is apparently a bug in the TreeView: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9d717ce0-ec6b-4758-a357-6bb55591f956/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just override the handler and don't call the base class function.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be just to kill the focus, just create your own class:

```
public class ViewOnlyTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox {
    // constants for the message sending
    const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
    const int WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if(m.Msg == WM_SETFOCUS) m.Msg = WM_KILLFOCUS;

        base.WndProc (ref m);
    }
}
```